# Meaning of values assigned to properties in R.java

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

What is the meaning of `0x7f05001c` in R.java file of an android project

```
public static final int action_bar = 0x7f05001c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.java is a auto generated file in which reference of resources such as strings, drawbles, layouts, and styles are automatically added. In your question `0x7f05001c` is just a reference id of `action_bar`.

For example:
in activity we always write

```
TextView v = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.something);
```

In this we are getting the reference of Texview which is automatically generated in R.java

Answer (score 1):

It's an example of a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) and the hexadecimal literal `0x7f05001c` is `2131034140` in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, that number is just a unique value assigned to an XML resource so you can create a Java object from it in your code: You can have multiple listviews in seperate XML layout's with the same ID, but they have their own unique int value so it can be distinguished.